# Client cannot receive data - Exception with socket.async_receive in client

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have a simple version of a client using boost asio. The client is suppose to receive a response from the server once it sends data. Here is the code of the client

```
void RunClient()
    {
        try
        {
            boost::asio::io_service io_service;
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query( "127.0.0.1", boost::lexical_cast< std::string >( 7777 )); //9100
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            socket.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buf_client, 3000), 0, ClientReceiveEvent);

            boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);

            boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
            std::cout << "Sending message \n";
            boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer("Data to send"), ignored_error);
            io_service.run();
        }
        catch (std::exception & ex)
        {
            std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< "] Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;   
        }
    }
```

Here is my ClientReceiveEvent

```
void ClientReceiveEvent(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if(!error)
        {
            std::cout << "Message: " << buf_client.data() << std::endl;

        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error occurred." << error.message() << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error from the above method for incoming data

```
Error occurred.The file handle supplied is not valid
```

Any suggestion what i am doing wrong in the client ?

**Update:**

I got the code working however I am confused as to why the statement

```
socket->async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buf_client, 3000), 0, ClientReceiveEvent);
```

needs to be placed after connect. and why the statement

```
io_service->run();
```

needs to be placed at the end. I thought this starts the asynch process.

I also wanted to know how would i resend data to the server. I could send it once successfully. How do i resend the command again?

The working code is:

```
boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service > io_service(new boost::asio::io_service);
            boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket > socket(   new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket( *io_service ) );
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(*io_service);
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query( "127.0.0.1", boost::lexical_cast< std::string >( 7777 )); //9100
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
            socket->connect(endpoint_iterator->endpoint());
            socket->async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buf_client, 3000), 0, ClientReceiveEvent);
            boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
            std::cout << "Sending message \n";
            boost::asio::write(*socket, boost::asio::buffer("some data"), ignored_error);           
            io_service->run();
```

Comment: Even though the `async_receive` will only execute after you've called run(), it might still require a connected socket at the time you call `async_receive`. Have you tried changing the order of `connect` and `async_receive`?

Comment: Just updated my post. It still does not work

Comment: your code still calls `async_receive` before  `connect`. Internally, this may (I'm guessing here) post the internal socket handle to the sockets service object. If my guess is right, then the synchronous write should succeed and after that the async_receive should fail.

Comment: If you expect an answer after you send the data, why are you trying to receive the data before the send? Move the async_receive after write and it should work.

Comment: @Loghorn, the async_receive will only execute after run() is called.

Comment: @dhavenith the receive itself is executed after the run, but not the function async_receive, that before scheduling the job checks for the socket status and since it's not yet connected, it will simply schedule a failure. Moving the async_receive after the connect will suffice, as you suggested, but I think that moving after the write is more clean and describes better the intention of the code.

Comment: @Longhorn I also wanted to know how would i resend data to the server. I could send it once successfully. How do i resend the command again ?

Answer (score 0):

Although `async_receive` schedules a read action that will execute after the code calls `run()`, it still needs a connected socket at the moment you are calling the `async_receive` function itself. This is because internally, `async_receive` is implemented as follows:

```
this->get_service().async_receive(this->get_implementation(),buffers, 0, BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(ReadHandler)(handler));
```

The `this->get_implementation()` expression returns a copy of the internal socket handle *as it is at that time*, unconnected in your case.

In other words, after the async read has been scheduled, it won't help connecting the socket, because the read will have been scheduled on an unconnected socket.

Comment: Currently my io_service->run() is placed after a message is sent. What if i want to send another message after that ?

Comment: @MistyD, that depends. If the second write is a reaction to a receive, you just call (async_)write in the receive handler (typically together with an async_receive, to keep on reacting on new incoming data). That is typically how a service is built with asio.
Alternatively, if you change your write into an async write, you could perform a second write in the write handler of that first write.

Comment: what if its not and I want to place it after io_service->run() ?

Comment: @MistyD, the run() function will block until all work has been processed. In your example, this will happen after the receive has been handled.
Doing stuff (except for cleanup) after run() is not typical asio usage, I'd say. Typically in asio, you'd "daisy chain" your actions by starting new actions in the completion handlers of previous ones.